# Merging two dataframes of different length, on a particular column with different number of instances

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes D1 and D2. Both are of different sizes but have some relation. D1 has a column "ID" has has multiple instances of the same ID and D2 has only a single instance. So how can I concatenate these two dataframes together?

```
    D1:                             D2:
    ID  val1  val2                  ID   Target   
    1    x     y                    1      0
    1    x     y                    2      1
    2    a     b
    2    a     c
```

So here I need to have a new column in D1 called as target for every row in D1 with the corresponding value from D2

```
    ID  val1  val2 Target   
    1    x     y     0
    1    x     y     0
    2    a     b     1
    2    a     c     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Option 1: `join`***
*This solution requires that you set the index of `D2` and use the `on` parameter*

```
D1.join(D2.set_index('ID'), on='ID')

   ID val1 val2  Target
0   1    x    y       0
1   1    x    y       0
2   2    a    b       1
3   2    a    c       1
```

**Note:** if `D2` doesn't include all values in `D1.ID` and you want a null value for the rows of `D1` where that is true, then use the `how='left'` option.

```
D1.join(D2.set_index('ID'), on='ID', how='left')
```

***from comments:***

> Why does this require setting the index of D2? The other answers don't do that. – ErikE
>
> @ErikE that is the difference between merge and join. pandas.DataFrame.merge will perform its merging on column values by default. While join looks at the index by default. I can override joins behavior by specifying a column to join on with on='ID'. However, that override ability is limited to the left object only. So, I have to set the index of the right object in order to execute appropriately. – piRSquared

***Option 2: `map` + `assign`***
*This solution is going to turn `D2` into something `dict` like, a `pd.Series` with the index being the `'ID'`s and the values being the `'Target'`.  `map` converts the `'ID'` column on `D1` into new values and we assign it to a new column with `assign`.*

```
D1.assign(Target=D1.ID.map(D2.set_index('ID').Target))


   ID val1 val2  Target
0   1    x    y       0
1   1    x    y       0
2   2    a    b       1
3   2    a    c       1
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, I'd appreciate knowing why so I can improve the answer or address any concerns.  These are two very appropriate methods for completing this task.

Comment: Why does this require setting the index of `D2`? The other answers don't do that.

Comment: @ErikE that is the difference between `merge` and `join`.  `pandas.DataFrame.merge` will perform its merging on column values by default.  While `join` looks at the index by default.  I can override `join`s behavior by specifying a column to join on with `on='ID'`.  However, that override ability is limited to the `left` object only.  So, I have to set the index of the `right` object in order to execute appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Your explanation might be better as part of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You want to left [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging):

```
In [36]:
D1.merge(D2, on='ID', how='left')

Out[36]:
   ID val1 val2  Target
0   1    x    y       0
1   1    x    y       0
2   2    a    b       1
3   2    a    c       1
```

This matches on common column 'ID' and left merges similar to SQL style merge

Answer (score 0):

```
D1.merge(D2, how='left', on="ID")
```

This is the equivalent of a SQL left join. This means that every values of D1 is kept and any value which matches on the ID of D2 will be added.